# JAXB unmarshalls to ElementNSImpl instead of generic type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am attempting to unmarshall XML using [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html) 2.3.1 with Java 8 & Java 11. I was given a new requirement that the nested elements `<Genre>` can be one of 2 different complex types, depending on the top most element.

Simplified Title Example:

```
<Title>
  <Country name="USA">
    <Genre>Western</Genre>
    <Genre>Drama</Genre>
  </Country>
</Title>
```

Simplified Release Example:

```
<Release>
  <Country name="USA">
    <Genre>
      <Value lookup="true">Horror</Value>
      <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    </Genre>

    <Genre>
      <Value lookup="true">Thriller</Value>
      <Sequence>2</Sequence>
    </Genre>
  </Country>

</Release>
```

The Java model previously only used `String` for genre, and unmarshalling results in the expected instance types for all levels of the model classes (`Title`, `List<Country>`, `List<String>`) with the Title Example:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Country")
class Country {
  @XmlElement(name = "Genre")
  List<String> genre;   // NOTICE THE TYPE String
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Title")
class Title {
  @XmlElement(name = "Country")
  List<Country> country;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Release")
class Release {
  @XmlElement(name = "Country")
  List<Country> country;
}
```

To support the new requirement, I had the idea to use generics to parameterize the type for genre. But with this implementation, unmarshalling results in the desired model types for only Title, Release, & Country.

Unfortunately, for Genre fields unmarshalling shows model types:

- `List<ElementNSImpl>` when I expect `List<String>` for the Title example,
- `List<ElementNSImpl>` when I expect `List<Genre>` for the Release example.

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Country")
class Country<T> {
  @XmlElement(name = "Genre")
  List<T> genre;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Title")
class Title {
  @XmlElement(name = "Country")
  List<Country<String>> country;   // NOTICE THE TYPE String
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Genre")
public class Genre {
  @XmlElement(name = "Value")
  public String value;

  @XmlElement(name = "Sequence")
  public String sequence;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Release")
class Release {
  @XmlElement(name = "Country")
  List<Country<Genre>> country;   // NOTICE THE TYPE Genre
}
```

I know the code using a `class Genre` works because I made a build avoiding the generic parameter and the result instances are for class `Genre` instead of `ElementNSImpl`.

I noticed that it is important to specify the classes when creating the JAXB Context. In the code I inherited, I see it specifies the package instead. I doubt if that is the problem because unmarshalling works without the generic parameter. Specifying the package is convenient because the actual models and XML are much more complex.

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true); 
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStringInput)));

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext("com.bar.foo.model", null);
jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(doc);
```

Comment: Plan B: just use two different Country classes for Title & Release

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov agreed, but my classes have many more fields so I don't want to risk any maintenance oversights. I'll see if I can get inheritance to cover it.

Comment: well, inheritance looks like it works, but it caused a ton of code duplication. I'd still like to know why generics don't work with JAXB.